# Cygwin: man no longer works

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, man

I have cygwin installed in the default folder (C:\cygwin) on Windows 7 Pro. Up until a few months ago (not sure how long), man pages worked fine. Then came an update, and now `man anything` displays nothing other than `(END)`. I have tried from my regular user account, and also from an elevated admin account. No joy.

I'm quite sure that Comodo Firewall's Defense+ heuristics broke the install by sandboxing an update component (D+ squawks about autorebase and setup_x86 every damn time), but I know it's not actively interfering with displaying man pages (I turned it off, and the problem persists). So the man system itself is broken. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Note: I also tried running makewhatis, with no success.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like I fixed the problem on my own with help from SpaghettiCat in the #cygwin channel on freenode. Things I checked before figuring out the problem:

- I checked the value of $PAGER and $MANPAGER (they were blank)
- I tried setting the value of both to "less" (no joy)
- I tried feeding a known man page to man, via `man /usr/share/man/man8/fdisk.8.gz` (still no joy)
- I swapped out a copy of `/etc/man.conf` with one from a known-working cygwin install. (no dice)

At this point, it was clear that more was messed up than just man. I figured I would have to trash my install. However, I discovered the `cygcheck -c` command, which I ran. The result: half of my packages were "Incomplete", including groff. Thanks, Microsoft System Restore!

After running cygwin's setup_x86.exe, and reinstalling the borked packages, everything's fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem and I managed to trace it down the to a corrupt `cygwin1.dll`.
I found that for some reason (*run installer while `bash` was running?*) there were 2 files in my `/bin` folder, and the newer-one was disabled:

```
* cygwin1.dll     (3148035 bytes, v1.7.30, APIv-0.272)
* cygwin1.dll.new (3156896 bytes, v1.7.32, APIv-0.274)
```

To fix it i had to re-install the package `base/cygwin: the UNIX emulation engine`.
Then I run `mandb`, just to be sure...

(NOTE that `cygcheck -c` had not reported any problems!)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same problem by setting `MANPATH` to an empty string (`MANPATH=`) and then troubleshooting its original contents.  It turned out that the entry to `/usr/share/man` started with a double slash. On Unix multipla shlashes anywhere in the path are a no-up. On Windows (and apparently CygWin) the double slash at the beginning of a path denotes a network share.  This caused the command to fail.